# I need to show table row on asp linkbutton

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In asp.net Project, firstly I have to hide the  table row and when click on linkbutton then show this table row. So I call a function on OnClientClick of link button with name ShowDiv. Now issue is that after calling that function, It again go to document.readyfunction.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#trUpdateImportEmail").hide();
    });
    function ShowDiv() {
        $("#trUpdateImportEmail").show()
    }
</script>

 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdateEmail" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" Text='Update Import Email' OnClientClick="Show()"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup for the link button? Does the page reload when you click the button?

Comment: @Rob Lang: Please check now . I also try to set default display :none for  'trUpdateImportEmail' , and linkbutton will call ShowDiv function. But still getting the same issue

Comment: You need to `OnClientClick="return Show()"`. This is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code document is reloaded on click button. So prevent document reload by using **return false** or **event.preventdefault()** in your function.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#trUpdateImportEmail").hide();
});
function ShowDiv() {
    $("#trUpdateImportEmail").show();
    return false;
}
```

Or

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#trUpdateImportEmail").hide();
});
function ShowDiv(event) {
    event.preventdefault();
    $("#trUpdateImportEmail").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because asp:LinkButton is a server side control, it will eventualy postback.
when your debugger "jumps" again to the document.ready, it because the page has probably been reloaded.

when using OnClientClick, it doesn't replace the LinkButton behavior (i.e postback), it just runs before it.

try returning false from the js function (because it returns true).
and let your OnClientClick look like:

```
return ShowDiv();
```